# Trying to read and print local file to console

Tags: javascript, ubuntu

I'm new to JS and I'm trying to just print the "loadavg" file to the console when I run my program. I don't want to bother doing it through the browser just yet.

This is what I've come up with

```
function readTextFile() {
  var contents = new File();
  contents.readTextFile("file:///proc/loadavg");
  console.log(contents);
}
```

I get no errors but the code still will not work

Comment: Um, JavaScript does not have builtin methods to read a file like that. There are ways to read a file, but the user would need to select it with a file input.

Comment: What is this `File` object with a `readTextFile` method?  I'm not familiar with this API.  If you're running this in Node, what package did you import for this?  If you're not running this in Node, how are you running it?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Answer (score 2):

With Node JS.

Create a folder and enter it:

```
mkdir filereader 
cd filereader
```

Init Node JS:

```
npm init
```

Edit `index.js` as new file in the directory:

```
var fs = require('fs'); 

let filename = '/proc/loadavg';
fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(data)
  });
```

Save, exit the file, and run the script:

```
node index.js
```

Image here in the link:
[running the script on Ubuntu Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbRmY.png)

Comment: is there any way I could assign data to a global variable? the eventual goal is to take information from multiple computers and assign their values to an array of variables and format it such that you can see the loads of multiple computers at once.

Comment: Ben, thanks, would you accept the response please?
I guess I would try to install a light services that pushes those values to the central machine. NodeJs can still serve you for that.
The central machines becomes just a listener and stores the data it receives before formatting and showing. If one of the computer goes down the infrastructure can keep going on.
It's just a guessing

Comment: Janitha's comment about streams would do  for your reading... then you'll figure out the pushing and saving of the data

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use nodeJS the only way to read text file using javascript is to use file Input

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="file_input">
```

JS:

```
const fileInput = document.getElementById("file_input")

fileInput.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0]
    if(file){
        const reader = new FileReader()
        reader.readAsText(file)
        reader.onload = () => console.log(reader.result)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nodejs streams to achieve this.

```
const fs = require('fs'),

var reader = fs.createReadStream('./proc/loadavg'); 
stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
    process.stdout.write(chunk);
});
```